# Ruby on Rails with Paperclip: can't find paperclip.rb initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

I recently installed the paperclip gem, and to use it with Amazon S3 I need to change the initializer, but I don't see it in config/initializers. How do I create it?/find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create paperclip.rb inside config/initializers/ on your own if it is not there.

For Paperclip with amazon s3 find this link
[Paperclip with amazon s3](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3)

Also you can see heroku [paperclip-amazons3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3)

Answer (score 0):

On this link you can find all the documentation that you need:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

My initializer looks like this:

```
    # config/initializers/paperclip.rb
    # only use Amazon S2 on production servers
    unless Rails.env.development?
      Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
      Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'

    # # config/initializers/paperclip.rb
    # Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
    end
```